# Getting values of each checkbox set based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to get separate lists of checked values based on the data attribute, using jQuery.

[image: Image Guide]

Following is my script, *edited from the original question*

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".refno", function () {
   var refindex = jQuery(this).data("refindex");
   //alert(refindex);
   jQuery('.datarefindex_'+ refindex ).each(function(){
        alert(refindex);//do your stuff here
   });
});
```

There is a variable number of checkbox lists under each `refindex`. So an `each` function is required in my opinion. Following is a sample of data I'm trying to capture. These data will be sent via an ajax request for processing along with some others.

Assume there are 3 sets of checkboxes in this scenario.

```
var list1 = array/list of checked items from list 1;
var list2 = array/list of checked items from list 2;
var list3 = array/list of checked items from list 3;
```

But when I try the above, all the checkboxes are selected (20 checkboxes for each list) which has `data-mainrefindex=refindex`. But I want to get only 3 variables as mentioned above.

Any support is appreciated. I hope I made my question clear.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure the checkbox situation from a screenshot but you can check if `jQuery("input[name=list1]:checked")` select all you checkbox and if your checkbox are really all checked (if the problem is the selector or the checkbox status).

Try to see in your code if the active items has a class to differentiate it from inactive, maybe you can select it all by using a class, if there is not an active class you can set it inside the onClick handler:

```
jQuery(this).addClass('.activeClass');
```

and the loop trough items using this selector:

```
`jQuery("input[name=list1].activeClass")`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object containing the Arrays and pass it on into the Ajax. See below. I have done only to add item to the array. Let me know if you want to remove the item from the Array when unchecked.

```
<div data-refindex='1'>
<input type="checkbox" value='1'/> 1
<input type="checkbox" value='2'/> 2
<input type="checkbox" value='3'/> 3
<input type="checkbox" value='4'/> 4
<input type="checkbox" value='5'/> 5
</div>
<div data-refindex='2'>
<input type="checkbox" value='6'/> 6
<input type="checkbox" value='7'/> 7
<input type="checkbox" value='8'/> 8
<input type="checkbox" value='9'/> 9
<input type="checkbox" value='10'/> 10
</div>
```

Javascript (jQuery Required)

```
var arraysObj = {};
$("div input").on('click',function(e){
  var arrayId = $(e.target).parent('div').data('refindex');
  if(typeof arraysObj['group_'+arrayId] === 'undefined')
    arraysObj['group_'+arrayId] = [];
  if ($(e.target).is(':checked') && $.inArray($(e.target).val(),arraysObj['group_'+arrayId]) === -1)
    arraysObj['group_'+arrayId].push($(e.target).val())
    console.log( JSON.stringify(arraysObj) );
})
```

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jc9f3Lv7/)